# Add picture to object javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hello so this might be a silly question to ask but I am a beginner in javascript and when I click on the button the images doesn't to appear it is only the link.
Thank you.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function fruit (name, colour, image){
       this.name = name;
       this.colour = colour; 
       this.image = image;

 } 
  var apple= new fruit("Apple", "Red", "http://www.lifemartini.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Apple-Fruit1.jpg");
  var banana = new fruit("Banana", "Yellow", "https://www.healthbytez.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/bana.jpg");
</script>
</head>

<body>
<button onclick= "myfunc()" id="button" name="button">button</button>
<section class="box special features">
      <div class="features-row">
       <section> 
        <h3 id="h31">&nbsp;</h3>
        <p id="p1">&nbsp;</p>
        <p id="p2">&nbsp;</p>
       </section>
       <section>
           <h3 id="h32">&nbsp;</h3>
           <p id="p3">&nbsp;</p>
        <p id="p4">&nbsp;</p>
       </section>
         </div>
     </section>
</body>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function myfunc(){
document.getElementById("h31").innerHTML = apple.name;
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = apple.colour;
document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = apple.image;
document.getElementById("h32").innerHTML = banana.name;
document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = banana.colour;
document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML = banana.image;
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
function myfunc() {
  var apple = new fruit("Apple", "Red", "http://www.lifemartini.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Apple-Fruit1.jpg");
  var banana = new fruit("Banana", "Yellow", "https://www.healthbytez.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/bana.jpg");
  document.getElementById("h31").innerHTML = apple.name;
  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = apple.colour;
  document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = '<img src="' +apple.image+ '" />';
  document.getElementById("h32").innerHTML = banana.name;
  document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = banana.colour;
  document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML = '<img src="' +banana.image+ '" />';
}

function fruit(name, colour, image) {
  this.name = name;
  this.colour = colour;
  this.image = image;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myfunc()" id="button" name="button">button</button>
<section class="box special features">
  <div class="features-row">
    <section>
      <h3 id="h31">&nbsp;</h3>
      <p id="p1">&nbsp;</p>
      <p id="p2">&nbsp;</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h3 id="h32">&nbsp;</h3>
      <p id="p3">&nbsp;</p>
      <p id="p4">&nbsp;</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to show images in HTML you should use `img` tag and it's `src` attribute, like below:

HTML

```
<img id="zzz" />
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("zzz").src = apple.image;
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer now that I think about it, it sounds like my question was useless ;)